# Source not found in eclipse remote debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have setup debuging environment with eclipse tomcat. I have added the source path in the debug configurations. When I debug the code it is stepping through java source code but when it comes to jsp it is aysing Source not found .. Edit Source lookup path.
When I clicked the Edit source look up path the jsp directory is already there to look up for debugging.
Still not trying to understand why it is complaining.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in the remote debug configuration your eclipse project is selected.